# how to select this out in ActiveRecord with a named count and a distinct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following structure / data:

```
global_id | list_type_id
4               2
11              2
4               2
4               2
7               2
7               2
```

and want to do something like:

```
GlobalList.select(:global_id).distinct.where('list_type_id=?',2).count('each_global_id')
```

with the following global_lists:

```
global_id:4, each_global_id:3
global_id:7, each_global_id:2
global_id:11, each_global_id:1
```

but the AR Query obviously doesn't work. Any ideas how to do it and get a named value for the count?

thx

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalList.where(:list_type_id => 2).group(:global_id).count
```

This will give you a hash with key as the global_is and the value as the count. Something like below for your example

```
{4 => 3, 7 => 2, 11 => 1}
```

**Update:**

You can reconstruct the result hash into the format you want.

```
{4 => 3, 7 => 2, 11 => 1}.collect{|key, value|{:global_id => key, :each_global_id => value}}
```

will give you

```
[{:global_id=>4, :each_global_id=>3}, {:global_id=>7, :each_global_id=>2}, {:global_id=>11, :each_global_id=>1}]
```

Comment: any way I can specify the keys in the resulting hash? Need to drop in for a current method.

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope that's the format you are expecting